# Get Method, Insert, and Remove At Methods For a Custom Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I am having a great deal of trouble trying to implement these three methods in a custom Linked List I am creating. The get(int pos) method will return null for everything but the 0th index even when I have an existing Linked List! My removeAt(int pos) and insert(int pos, int n) methods are having the same trouble. I'll include everything I believe is relevant.

**My Node Class**

```
    public class MyNode 
   {
      public int cargo;
      public MyNode next;

      public MyNode()
      {
        cargo = 0;
        next = null;
      }

      public MyNode(int i)
      {
        cargo = i;
        next = null;
      }
   }
```

**My Custom Linked List**

```
public class MyLinkedList 
{
MyNode head;
int size;

public MyLinkedList()
{
    head = null;
    size = 0;
}

public int get(int pos)
{
    MyNode current = new MyNode();
    for(int i = 0; i <= pos && current != null; i++)
    {
        if(pos == 0){
            current = head;
        }else{
            current = current.next;
            break;
        }
    }
    return current.cargo;
}

public void insert(int pos, int n)
{
    MyNode current = new MyNode(n);
    MyNode before = new MyNode(get(pos-1));
    if(before.next != null)
    {
        before.next = current.next;
    }
    else
    {
        before.next = current;
    }
    size++;
    System.out.println("Inserted " + n + " at position " + pos);
}
public void removeAt(int pos)
{
    MyNode before = new MyNode(get(pos -1));
    MyNode remove = new MyNode(get(pos));
    MyNode after = null;

    int cargo = remove.cargo;

    if(remove.next != null)
    {
        after = remove.next;
    }
    before.next = after;
    size--;
    System.out.println("Removed " + cargo + " from position " + pos);
}
}
```

**My Test Data**

```
l.add(17);
l.add(14);
l.add(43);
l.add(50);
System.out.println(l.get(1));
```

returns a NullPointer Exception at the sysout

Answer (score 0):

You are creating too many items. `insert` is creating 2 items, only the first one is needed. `removeAt` is creating 2 more nodes.. Most of these need to be removed.

Make the below changes and test again.

```
MyNode before = get(pos-1);

MyNode before = get(pos -1);
MyNode remove = get(pos);
```

Edit:.. Even `MyNode current = new MyNode();` in `get` is unnecessary.

Edit: Your **core issue** is that `get` returns the data and not the element, you should write a version that returns the `Node` and use that in all internal methods, like above. The current way has you making new nodes that are immediately destroyed because they are not properly inserted to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, regarding your `get` problem, you're breaking out of the loop if `pos != 0`.

Also, your exit conditions for the list are wrong.  It should be `< pos` not `<= pos`.

Also, there is a chance that current will be null when your loop exists and will then get a null pointer exception.